# "more than pack" or "more than packing"

Tags: word-usage, tense

> A sugar study published in the Journal of the American Medical Association, finds sugar does more than just ***pack*** on the pounds.

From the dictionary, I know that *pack on the pounds* means *to gain weight*, but *pack* here, I guess, is used as a *verb*. So should it more appropriate to substitute *packing* for *pack*? Just as follows:

> A sugar study published in the Journal of the American Medical Association, finds sugar does more than just ***packing*** on the pounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to be about the use of **packing** or *pack**.

It is fine to use the bare infinitive after "to do", as in the following examples:

> What *does* sugar **do** to you?
>   It packs one the pounds, doesn't it?
>   Yes, it *does* **make** you fat.

You would not see this written (or hear this spoken) as:

> *What *does* sugar **doing** to you?
>   It packs one the pounds, doesn't it?
>   *Yes, it *does* **making** you fat.

So similarly, if it does more than one thing, we still use the same form:

> What *does* sugar **do** to you?
>   It *does* **make** you fat.
>   Well, it *does* more than **pack** on the pounds.

Comment: Yes, great examples. However, we could say, "Do you see what sugar **is doing** to you?" "Yes, I'm **packing** on the pounds." That's one way to make the *-ing* form grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a verb.  Pack is a verb; pack on pounds is an idiomatic way to say gain weight.  Does or makes is simply the wrong verb in English for what sugar does.  What sugar does, as oerkelens has said, is cause weight gain.  We wouldn't typically say sugar that does pack on pounds; "There is sugar that doesn't pack on pounds and sugar that does [pack on pounds]." is an example of where we would use it.

Answer (score 0):

Think this way and it'll go better.

> A sugar study published in the Journal of the American Medical Association, finds sugar does more than just [pack on the pounds] *weight gain*.

We often refer the phrase like '[Foods that pack on the pounds](http://www.chicagonow.com/get-fit-chicago/2014/01/10-foods-that-drain-energy-and-pack-on-the-pounds/)'. Here, sugar is one of the foods that **pack on the pounds.**

As you said, *Pack on the pounds* is an idiom used to describe weight gain.

> [Pack on the pounds (idiomatic)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pack_on_the_pounds) - to gain weight.

Comment: "sugar does more than just weight gain" is not grammatical, compare "sugar does weight gain". "sugar does more than pack on the pounds" -> "sugars packs on the pounds". You mention that _pack on_ is a verb, then you cannot replace that verb with a noun in a sentence (weight gain is a noun!). Also "gain weight" would not work, as the sugar does not gain weight, but the person eating it does.

Comment: @oerkelens First, I said **think this way** to understand it better. At times, we (I'm a healthcare provider) often say it that way. *What extra sugar does to you?* can be answered *It (sugar) does weight gain.*

Comment: @oerkelens You don't need to replace a verb there. I asked to remove the whole phrase and replace it with simply weight-gain (or say obesity). *A sugar study published in the Journal of the American Medical Association, finds sugar does more than just [pack on the pounds] obesity.*

Comment: @oerkelens edited. Hope this is better now.

Comment: No, "sugar does [noun]" is wrong :) The original "sugar does pack the pounds" is "sugar does [verb] [object]". You need a verb after "sugar does", and "weight gain is not a verb, so it will not work.

Comment: @oerkelens what's your take on *Food/s that pack(s) on the pounds.*?  http://magazine.foxnews.com/food-wellness/10-foods-pack-pounds-and-how-enjoy-them-guilt-free

Comment: I have no problem with that wording. I have a problem with the wording "food that weight gain", as I would have with the sentence "This man table." Do you see the difference between "weight gain" (gain = noun) and "gain weight" (gain = verb)?

Comment: @oerkelens I absolutely agree but then I stated that healthcare providers do describe these things this way. Now see the Fox News that say *Foods that (do) Pack on Pounds.* that may further be called as *Sugar that does pack on pounds*, right?

Comment: Yes, but _not_ sugar does weight gain! Sugar  can _cause_ weight gain, but it doesn't "do" weight gain.